# IntelliJ running with TestNG hang at "running tests" forever

Tags: intellij-idea, testng, intellij-14

I'm using IntelliJ 14.1.7 and testng 6.10.

After test case finished, TestNG is still running and never finish.

[image: running forever]

I believe this is a IntelliJ configuration issue since `maven clean test` finish normally.

Any help?

Comment: Does it still happen in the current IDE version?

Comment: not sure, I don't have update to date IntelliJ IDEA ultimate version

Comment: You can try with the trial version.

Comment: I tried 2016 community version, it works fine. Looks like it's time to upgrade...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be an old bug that is already resolved in the [current IntelliJ IDEA version](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html).